# Entity framework issue- The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Hi I am using CodeFirst approach to create database but I am getting below error

***The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.***

The entities are following

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public int ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModifiedByUserId")]
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class User : EntityBase
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks
Vinod

Comment: Perhaps, you must add your relational properties to User class, not to abstract class.

Comment: what do you mean by adding relational properties. Do you want to keep CreatedBy/ModifiedBy in User table itself

Comment: Yes, I think so, because I think that EF Code First never create Table for abstract class. But I never come across such situation.

Comment: I know it doesn't create but if you look at the EntityBase it has reference to User table and when it will go to create userTable then there will be conflict

Comment: Please check your code without abstract keyword.